# Multiple and condition with joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I am trying to find a record in a single MySQL query but I can't please have a look and help me if you know anything.

```
products(Table 1)
id  | title
----------
1   | Test 1
2   | Test 2
3   | Test 3

nutritions (Table 2)
id | product_id | title    | evaluation(string)
-------------------------------
1  | 1          | calories | 8
2  | 3          | proteins | 5
3  | 3          | calories | 8
4  | 3          | Sugar    | 9
5  | 2          | calories | 8
6  | 2          | Sugar    | 9
```

I want to apply a filter on the products table as below.

case 1:

`(nutritions.title = 'calories' AND nutritions.evaluation = '8') and (nutritions.title = 'Sugar' AND nutritions.evaluation = '9')`

case 2:

`(nutritions.title = 'calories' AND nutritions.evaluation = '8') and (nutritions.title = 'Sugar' AND nutritions.evaluation = '9') and (nutritions.title = 'proteins' AND nutritions.evaluation = '5')`

expected output:

```
products(case 1)                       products(case 2)
id  | title                            id  | title
----------                            --------------
2   | Test 2                           3   | Test 3
3   | Test 3
```

I tried the below query but it takes time I have more than 70k products.

```
Product.find_by_sql("
        select `products`.* from products 
            JOIN nutritions where products.id = nutritions.product_id 
                and (nutritions.title = 'calories' and nutritions.evaluation = '8') 
                and nutritions.product_id IN(
                        select product_id 
                        from nutritions 
                        where nutritions.title = 'Sugar' 
                        and nutritions.evaluation = '9'
                        )
            ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.  One method is to use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1
              from nutritions n
              where n.product_id = p.id and
                    n.title = 'calories' and
                    n.evaluation = '8'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from nutritions n
              where n.product_id = p.id and
                    n.title = 'Sugar' and
                    n.evaluation = '9'
             ) ;
```

With an index on `nutritions(product_id, title, evaluation)`, this should have very good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a column cannot be 2 or more things at the same time, by that I meam
`nutritions.title` cannot be `calories` and `Sugar`

So instead of using AND use OR

```
    (nutritions.title = 'calories' AND nutritions.evaluation = '8') 
OR  (nutritions.title = 'Sugar' AND nutritions.evaluation = '9')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i want the exact same product so I have to you AND condition.